# Issue filling in form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webforms, javascript-injection

I'm trying to write a javascript script which tries to fill in an ASP form. The problem is that when I set, for example, the username, the browser loads a new HTML with nothing but the value I've just set. This happens in 2 `<input>` and 1 `<select>` fields, just the same thing.

Could someone tell me what could be happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the answer to the problem. I thought about posting it here cause it could be useful for some people that could be having the same problem.

So when I wrote something like:

`javascript: document.getElementById('username').value="user1";`

The web was redirecting me to another page, completely blank, just showing **user1** on it.

I found `void();` javascript function, what it makes is executing the code inside it without having a return value (not showing the page in my case). And this code, made the trick:

`javascript: void(document.getElementById('username').value="user1");`

Hopefully it will be useful for someone else